# how to use "USING" keyword to join three table and display it using mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, using

this is how i manage to join the table using inner join

```
SELECT lab5enrollment.matricno, lab5student.stuname, 
lab5enrollment.courseid, 
lab5course.cname
FROM ((lab5enrollment
INNER JOIN lab5student ON lab5enrollment.matricno = lab5student.matricno)
INNER JOIN lab5course ON lab5enrollment.courseid = lab5course.courseid)
WHERE lab5enrollment.courseid = 'CSF3402';
```

this is how i used the using keyword to join the table but i dont know how to join the three table...

```
SELECT matricno, stuname, courseid, cname
FROM lab5enrollment
JOIN lab5student
USING (matricno) 
WHERE courseid = 'CSF3402';
```

i want to observe the differrence between using the inner join and using...

Comment: Stop there. Dont do it. Always prefer to use `ON` based join

Answer (score 0):

You should probably lean towards using joins with explicit `ON` clauses for a number of reasons.  If you wanted to use `USING` here, then the following should work:

```
SELECT
    t1.matricno,
    t2.stuname,
    t1.courseid,
    t3.cname
FROM lab5enrollment t1
INNER JOIN lab5student t2
    USING (matricno)
INNER JOIN lab5course t3
    USING (courseid)
WHERE
    t1.courseid = 'CSF3402';
```

This assumes that `lab5enrollment` and `lab5student` both have a column with the same name `matricno`, and that `lab5student` and `lab5course` both have a column called `courseid`.